# Commit transaction in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, transactions, dbcontext

I'm adding an entry to DB in a foreach loop and using transactions. But I'm getting this error:

```
The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction.
```

***UPDATE*** :

```
        var user = await CurrentUser;

        if (user.IsNotNull())
        {
                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var reports = new List<ReportEntity>();

                        foreach (var model in modelList)
                        {
                            reports.Add(new ReportEntity
                            {
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                UserId = user.Id,,
                                ReportTypeId =  ReportTypeId
                            });
                        }

                        await _context.tbl_Reports.AddRangeAsync(reports);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await transaction.CommitAsync();
                        resp.Status = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        resp.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
                        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    }
                } //End of transaction
            }
         }
        else
        {
            resp.ErrorMessage = "User not found";
        }
```

I'm adding records in a loop depending on the array of objects in POST. When do I commit the transaction so I don't get this error?

Comment: If `user` is null, how transaction gets completed? Because if it doesn't, I guess it can pop up in another EF context, as contexts do re-use the same connections, they don't created them anew each time.

Comment: @cassandrad When user is null, I return an error message and it returns 'resp' which carries that error message. But when user is not null, I'm getting that error `The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction.`

Comment: When `user` is null, how do you call `CommitAsync()`?

Comment: @cassandrad I'm not calling `CommitAsync()` when user is null. It goes to the else block and returns resp

Comment: Maybe you should try to call it as transaction should be closed even if you don't change anything.

Comment: `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` Does this commit the transaction?

Comment: No, `SaveChangesAsync` doesn't. `transaction.CommitAsync()` and `transaction.RollbackAsync();` does.

Comment: @cassandrad Yep, you're right. Somehow I had in mind they would interfere or you needed to set a flag ... that doesn't seem to be the case, though.

Comment: 1) is there a chance that several threads simultaneously get access to the same EF context, for example, via static field? 2) is there any third party libs that interact with db, like batch insert? 3) can `await CurrentUser` interact with database?

Comment: 1) I was calling another function which was opening transaction so I'd nested it. Thank you for your help! @cassandrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't closing the transaction in case when `user` is null. Here what actually happens in your code:

1. you call the method that calls `_context.Database.BeginTransaction()`
2. a transaction is opened for a connection
3. `user` is null, which leads to not calling `CommitAsync` or `RollbackAsync`
4. transaction is still in use even after method execution is finished, it is open on a connection
5. you call that method again, maybe creating a new EF context, however, EF context does not create a new connection each time, it will re-use existing one from connection pool
6. EF context picks a connection that was utilized on step 2, with already opened transaction
7. you try to open another transaction on a connection that has already opened transaction and you get exception (even if this time `user` isn't null)

I guess it should be working that way. You can try and commit/rollback transaction even if nothing in database has been changed, that should remove the issue.

Documentation on [SqlConnection.BeginTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) says:

> You must explicitly commit or roll back the transaction using the Commit or Rollback method.

**UPDATE**
If mentioned above didn't help, there are other things that should be considered and inspected:

- There are third-party libraries that interact with database and open transactions. Sometimes they help to work with EF and provide such functionality as `BatchInsert` or `BatchUpdate`. They could be called in your code somewhere.
- Simultaneous access to a single EF context, if it's stored in, for example, static field and several threads are trying to use it at the same time.
- External code can create a transaction before your code has been called, also your code can create a transaction in nested calls.

Pay attention to all places where EF context that cases the exception is used.

Comment: Might be worth adding: OP might be assuming Dispose is rolling back the transaction, like TransactionScope would. If you look at the remarks for DbTransaction.Dispose in the docs it states: "Dispose should rollback the transaction. However, the behavior of Dispose is provider specific, and should not replace calling Rollback"

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yeah, probably I might be wrong in my assumption. Would expect from `Dispose` to roll back the transaction, too.

Comment: I have updated my code and I'm still getting the same error. My question also has the updated code.